# Glob pattern condition in if statement

Tags: bash

I have a simple for-loop that iterates over a glob-pattern and enters an `if` condition, for when the directory path is not equal to `*/venv` then print the file. How can I get this working in the `if` statement?

For example:

```
for file in ML*/*; do if [ "$file" != */venv ]; then echo $file ; fi; done
```

Is what I have tried, but it prints out:

```
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
[: too many arguments
...
...
```

The following implementation works for `*/venv`:

```
for file in ML*/*; do if [[ "$file" != */venv]]; then find $file ; fi; done
```

And if I wanted to exclude multiple paths:

```
for file in ML*/*; do if [[ "$file" != */venv && "$file" != */ENV_DIR ]]; then find $file ; fi; done
```

However, this assumes only the inner directory. If I wanted to exclude all sub-directories that may have `venv` or `ENV_DIR` so `*/*/venv, */*/*/venv` etc ..., how do I take this into consideration?

I have attempted the above with the following:

```
for file in ML*/*;
do for innerFile in $file*/*;
 do if [[ "$innerFile" != */venv && "$innerFile" != */ENV_DIR && "$file" != */venv && "$file" != */ENV_DIR ]];
  then find $innerFile ; fi;  done; done
```

However, the nested loop only return inner-subdirectories, therefore `$file` is skipped and we only get `$file*/*` paths, but for further nested files like `ML/plot/something/distant/venv` this won't be captured and I'd have to nest even further. What is the most effective way to capture this nested exclusion?

The below solution does not work and still will include `venv`, or other directories that I want excluded. I found that the following works:

```
find ML*/* -not -path "*/venv/**"  -not -path "*/ENV_DIR/**" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do if [[ "$file" != */venv && "$file" != */ENV_DIR ]]; then echo $file; fi; done
```

This will only return the subdirectories and those files which do not contain `venv` or `ENV_DIR`, therefore, completing my previous proposal.

However, when I change `echo $file` to `find $file` the excluded directory path appears for `ENV_DIR` and I am not sure why because the `IF` condition should of removed it.

Comment: Use `[[ $file != */venv ]]` instead of `[ "$file" != */venv ]`. See [BashFAQ/031](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: Add some cases to your question (**no** comment) where $file should match and where not.

Comment: @Cyrus `cases` will be my next attempt after learning how `if` statements are properly implemented

Comment: @Emil11 Note that the `[` vs. `[[` issue has nothing to do with `if` statements.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin How do I instantiate an `OR` condition for example If I wanted it to not equal two different patterns such as ```[[ "$file" != (*/venv | */ENV_DIR) ]]```, this will give `venv` files but not `ENV_DIR`, whats the correct implementation

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Right, this [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs) suggests it enables the matching of wild-card patterns which is what I needed

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I figured this was the only alternative, I had imagined there was a one-liner!

Comment: BTW, one often would use a `case` statement here. `case $file in */venv|*/ENV_DIR) :;; *) echo "$file";; esac` works not just in bash but also in POSIX sh, which doesn't support `[[` or extglobs.